# IE - no longer possible to remove box outline?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

the usual way to remove the IE link outline no longer seems to work for me - I'm using IE9 which doesn't have the outline, but when I switch back to 7 or 8 (using IE9's dev tools) the outline is there. My CSS is below - anyone any ideas?

```
a:active, a:selected { 
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: does it work in a real copy of IE7 or IE8? The compatibility modes are notorious for not being entirely accurate in their emulation of the older versions of IE, so beware of drawing conclusions just from testing with it.

Answer (score 1):

Please download a proper virtual machine environment that contains old versions of Internet Explorer.  It could be that the compatibility mode does not render your HTML the way it should.  The best way to test IE is to actually use IE in a clean environment.  You can download the App Compat VHDs here:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575

Answer (score 0):

Please download a proper emulater for old versions of Internet explorer. It could be that the compatibility mode does not render your code the way it should. The best emulator is The IE Tester, you can download a copy from here..

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage